# Rails validates acceptance not validating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I would like to simply validate a terms checkbox on my form. I have implemented the folowing:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :terms, acceptance: true
end
```

I have stripped the form back to the checkbox only for debugging purposes.

Regardless of the entry passed the :terms does not validate. The form parameters appear to being passed correctly.

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+1dzwEMajQN4cL7KdGjlIw2kFSyVk/36eAhNhdydUXhLfzyT7LnCiUGdfzYt3hD/dD7evIVMiVWePv+7p+scyA==", "user"=>{"terms"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

When I update the validation to the following I receive an error stating "Terms must be accepted" regardless of the terms value submitted. This leads me to believe the value from the form is not being passed to the validation.

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true, :allow_nil => false
```

Comment: Could you add a code snippet showing where you update/create the user in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

OK...

The problem was that the validation helper validates the contents of the row within the table before saving. For this to trigger I needed to assign the ":terms" value to the model for validation.

I was only passing the params hash with the "terms" item within it expecting that to be validated.